# Visual Basic: Creating a bitmap from path?

Tags: vb.net, path

```
Dim Image1 As New Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "\Resources\Pic1.png")
```

But I get an error.... It says invalid argument.
I want to create a bitmap from an image called Pic1.png found in the Resources folder of my application.

Comment: On compile, resources are usually built into the EXE, not actually stored in a folder, so follow binil's suggestio

Answer (score 1):

if you have the file in your `Resources` folder you can call it like `My.Resources.FileName`

```
Dim Image1 As New Bitmap(My.Resources.Pic1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid argument in this situation usually means file not found.  I think if you add a line before it with a msgbox( filename & " = " &  io.file.exists(filename)) you will see that.

If you really want to access it through the file system you need to set the properties of the file to copy local.

If you want to access it as a resource you need to add it to your project through the resource screen in the project properties.  Then you can access it using My.Resources.filename

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your debug or release folder that the exe is running from contains a folder named "resources" and contains "pic1.png". You may want to verify the path that application.startuppath points to like so:

```
MessageBox.show(application.startuppath)
```

Now when your program starts, you will be able to manually verify that it's doing what you think it should and the file is in the right location. You can also use the following to check if the file exists first:

```
Dim Image1 as Bitmap
If (System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\Resources\Pic1.png")) Then
    Image1 = New Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "\Resources\Pic1.png")
Else
    MessageBox.show("File: " & Application.StartupPath + "\Resources\Pic1.png" & " doesn't exist. Check file and try again.")
    End
End If
```

Let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: Ok the MessageBox throws me a path, and I try to follow it, but I can't find the AppData folder in c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Test\bin\Debug       .....In my solution explorer window I have a Resources folder and there is Pic1.png

Comment: Ok the MessageBox gives me a path to the Debug folder of my project. But here isn't where the Resources folder is! That's why I got the error.... but, how do I access the resources folder?

Comment: Application.StartupPath is pointing to the folder that your .exe file is starting from, which in this case is the debug folder. You have to either give the full path of the file and place the file there if you want to use Application.StartupPath, or if you want to use the file as a built in resource, you have to drag that file into your project->properties->resources window. Once you drag it into that window, change the property for that resource to "embedded in .resx". Now to access the resource, you have to use My.Resources.Pic1 That should do it for you.